# Regex: Get everything around a string

Tags: java, regex

```
<font color="black">
<font color="red">
<font color="white">
```

I need to capture everything around `color="*"`

With `color="(.*?)"` I can capture the color attribut, know i must invert it.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to capture everything except color="myColor" ?

Comment: @MattKelly Yes. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you want it in JavaScript regex (regex flavors differ from language to language).
Something like:

```
var htmlText = '<font color="black">\n' +
               '<font color="red">\n' +
               '<font color="white">';
var colorRegEx = /color=["']+([^\"\']*)["']+/ig;
while(colorRegEx.exec(htmlText)) {
    console.log(RegExp.$1);     //Should give you: black, red, white
}
```

Basically the regex says: look for 'color=' then at least 1, either single or double quote then get the value until we see another single or double quote.

Although if you are doing thing in your web application you probably want to use jQuery or some other JS library to help get the values.
e.g.

```
<div id="fred">
  <font color="black">Hello</font>
  <font color="red">I like</font>
  <font color="white">ice cream</font>
</div>
```

Then some jQuery to get the color values would be:

```
$.each($('#fred').children(), function(index, item) {
    console.log($(item).prop('color'));
});
```

Comment: Great answer! I'm sorry, but I need it for Java. Does it also work in Java?

Comment: Sorry I'm not a Java dev so I'm not entirely sure but the core RegEx is probably usable. I made this http://fiddle.re/77wtda but I'm too tired to get and setup JDK to actually try it out. (click the green Java button and then click Test)